# Prolong SQL column datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server

We have a column `char(16)` which needs to be as long as `char(128)`. How to change the datatype in SQL Server 2008 R2 if the table contains over 100 000 rows? It maybe doesn't matter though.

How expensive is this operation?

Comment: You should not be using SQL if you dont know how to do this or find out (very easily) how to do this.

Comment: Are you aware that a `CHAR(128)` column will **always** use 128 characters (bytes) of storage? It will always use the full length. For a length of that size, I'd strongly recommend using `VARCHAR(128)` instead - that only ever uses as much space as character are stored in it...

Comment: Re "how expensive is this operation?" The size of each data row is being extended by 116 bytes, which need to be inserted at the end of each field being extended, extending the data size by 11.5 MB (about 1400 pages).  It is likely that virtually all the data in the table will need to be physically moved across pages and extents.  As marc_s recommended, using variable-width columns could be may be preferable if the data stored in the column varies considerably across records, since extending the column capacity would not inherently require extending each individual data row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your table name is YourTable

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN YourCharColumn CHAR(128)
```

**or** in case some difficulties

```
ALTER TABLE YourTable ADD NewChar char(128) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT df DEFAULT OldChar
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP CONSTRAINT df
GO
ALTER TABLE YourTable DROP COLUMN OldChar
GO
exec sp_rename('YourTable.NewChar', 'OldChar', 'COLUMN')
```

Comment: +1. Might also have to `ALTER TABLE YourTable ALTER COLUMN NewChar CHAR(128) NULL` as the last step, if the column need not prohibit NULLs ultimately.

Comment: @AndriyM I think the author will understand that if column is nullable - then no needs in DEFAULT constraint and its dropping

Comment: Why, I thought, nay, I was sure, the idea of NOT NULL + DEFAULT was to initialise the new column with old values, and I quite agree with that. Otherwise you'd have to `UPDATE YourTable SET NewChar = OldChar`. That is, to summarise, if the column is originally NOT NULL and must remain so, you do all those steps in your second approach, but if the column should be NULL, you need *additionally* to ALTER it to be NULL. Or what am I missing?

Comment: @AndriyM - you missed nothing - it is all true, I choose the `NOT NULL` scenario as worst case, If column nullable then yes - it is the simple **add column/update** case.